# Query locally for objects with non-empty collection

Tags: breeze

I have a collection of objects called Parents (some without children yet), and a related collection of Children.

I have all parents and children cached locally.  For certain views I want to show just those Parents who have children.

I'm having trouble figuring how to do this.

I've tried

```
breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("Parents")
    .where("Children", "!=", null)
```

This returns all Parents.

I've also tried

```
breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("Children")
    .select("Parents")
```

This returns duplicate parents for families with more than one child.  In addition it returns simple objects, not breeze entities.

I've also tried

```
breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("Parents")
    .where("Children", "!=", [])
```

&

```
breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("Parents")
    .where("Children.length", ">", 0)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated post: 11/25/13

As of Breeze 1.4.6, 'any' and 'all' operators are now supported.

### Older post

Breeze doesn't **yet** support 'any' and 'all' query operators, (which is what would allow this operation) but they are on our roadmap. Please vote for this on the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3988038-adding-any-and-all-filter-operators).

If you only need to determine this locally then the easy workaround would probably be to just use this: ( untested code, so there might be typos).

```
// assuming "Parent" is the name of the entity type corresponding to the "Parents" endpoint
var parentEntitiesWithChildren = myEntityManager.getEntities("Parent").filter(function(parent) {
  return parent.getProperty("Children").length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was doing something similar with a for loop, but your solution is more concise.  User Voice appears to be down, so I'll check back later.